# Why do I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined(…)"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Error Message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined(…)

Line 44, Column 23

I have read every post I can find related to this error but have not found anything applicable to this situation.

I'm trying to take a string and turn it into an array of arrays that is formatted to take the shape of steps (codewars' kata); one word across, next word down and so on. The problem I'm running into is that I keep getting an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined(…) when trying to use the length of an array element within a for loop. So in this nested loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < masterStringOdd.length; i++){
    temp2 = proArr.slice(0);
    start2 = even[i].length - 1;
    for(let j = 0; j < odd[i].length; j++){
        let replace2 = masterStringOdd.charAt(i);
        Array.prototype.splice.apply(temp2, [start2, 1].concat(replace2));
        finalOdd.push(temp2);
    }
    start2 += even[i+1].length - 1;    
}
```

With the last line "start2 += even[i+1].length - 1;" (I have tried about a thousand different various of this) I get the error, but if I return that line "return even[i+1].length - 1;" I get 5, which is the correct length. My complete code is at the end of this email if anyone wants to look at it, and believe me I understand it is ridiculous and awkward (working code and completely unpolished) - skills at hand and all that.

Just can't figure out why I can't get and use the value of the element's length in this case. Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

```
function wordStep(str) {
    let array = str.split(" "); 
    let even = [], odd = [], proArr = [], finalEven = [], finalOdd = [];
    //for loop to create sperate arrays for across and down  
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if (i%2 === 0){
            even.push(array[i]);
        } else {
            odd.push(array[i].slice(1,-1));
        }
    } 
    //data collection and tool variables, might delete them if the are not    needed
    let finalLength = even.join("").toString().length - (even.length - 1);
    let masterStringEven = even.join("").toString();
    let yAxis = odd.join("").toString().length;
    let masterStringOdd = odd.join("").toString();  
    //for loop to create protype array
    for (let i = 0; i < finalLength; i++){
        proArr.push(",");
    }   
    // for loop to create final evens arrays
    let start = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < even.length; i++){
        let temp1 = proArr.slice(0);
        let replace = even[i].split("");
        Array.prototype.splice.apply(temp1, [start, replace.length].concat(replace));
        finalEven.push(temp1);
        start += replace.length-1;;
    }
    // nested loops for final odds' array
    let temp2 = []
    let start2 = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < masterStringOdd.length; i++){
        temp2 = proArr.slice(0);
        start2 = even[i].length - 1;
        for(let j = 0; j < odd[i].length; j++){
            let replace2 = masterStringOdd.charAt(i);
            Array.prototype.splice.apply(temp2, [start2, 1].concat(replace2));
            finalOdd.push(temp2);
        }
        start2 += even[i+1].length - 1;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Always state clearly **which line** the error is on, and *quote* the error verbatim.

Comment: @ Matthew: Fundamentally, what's happening is that you're going past the end of the `even` array, so `even[i]` gives you `undefined`, and then you try to read the `length` of `undefined`, which causes the error. Use the debugger built into the environment you're using (all browsers have them, and NodeJS has node-inspector, etc.) to step through the code statement by statement, examining variables as you go, and you'll see what's going wrong.

Comment: Earlier in the code I created two arrays even and odd. I was able to use a for loop that used the even[] to push into a new array, So I think they are initializing correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, what's happening is that you're going past the end of the `even` array, so `even[i]` gives you `undefined`, and then you try to read the `length` of `undefined`, which causes the error.

And indeed, we can see that in this loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < masterStringOdd.length; i++){
    temp2 = proArr.slice(0);
    start2 = even[i].length - 1;
    for(let j = 0; j < odd[i].length; j++){
        let replace2 = masterStringOdd.charAt(i);
        Array.prototype.splice.apply(temp2, [start2, 1].concat(replace2));
        finalOdd.push(temp2);
    }
    start2 += even[i+1].length - 1;    
}
```

...you're assuming that `masterStringOdd.length` will always be **less** than `even.length`. Nothing in the code ensures this, and in fact it will frequently not be true. `masterStringOdd.length` is the length of the `odd` array's entries joined together as a string; `even.length` is the number of `even` entries. So there are two reasons why `even.length` may not be at least as big as `masterStringOdd.length`: 1. The latter is the length of a string, not an array; and 2. The latter relates to `odd`, not `even`.

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder That's perfect, I was looking in the wrong direction as to the cause of the error. Given what you have pointed out I might have to rethink my approach to this problem. Not sure I can get the for loop to do what I want it to do. Thanks also for the "question" formatting advice. Matthew PS, tried to up vote you, but don't have the rep yet.

Comment: Crowder, I have a follow-up question for you if you have a moment.

Comment: In this code, I keep getting a Cannot read property error: 
Error: VM705:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined(…)
Line 10, Column 14
    
      function validName(array){
   let lower = []
   for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  lower.push(array[i].toLowerCase());
 } 
 let testA = []
 for(let i = 0; i < lower.length + 1; i++){
  let j = 1;
  if(lower[i].charAt(lower[i].length-1) === lower[i+1].charAt(i)){
  testA.push(lower[i]);
  j++;
  } 
 } return testA;
     }
I am doing something wrong with "property" in my code. I keep get this Er

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you are not checking the even and odd arrays length before accessing them. This will create issue if you have **str value in  wordStep(str)** which do not push values in these array at the indices where you are accessing those.

Put proper array length check for accessing the array at the particular index.

```
for(var i = 0; i < masterStringOdd.length; i++){
    temp2 = proArr.slice(0);
    if(even.legth > i)
    start2 = even[i].length - 1;
    if(odd.length > i){
    for(let j = 0; j < odd[i].length; j++){
        let replace2 = masterStringOdd.charAt(i);
        Array.prototype.splice.apply(temp2, [start2, 1].concat(replace2));
        finalOdd.push(temp2);
    }
    }
    if(even.length > i +1)
    {
      console.log(even.length);
      start2 += even[i+1].length - 1;  

    }
}
```

for example **wordStep("Life is good for us");** this call will fill the array properly and you will not get any error.

but if its **wordStep("Life Good");**, you will see the issue in your code if proper length check are not applied

plunker to verify : http://plnkr.co/edit/QQovAAzlDhXgucikCGAb?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the excellent suggestion. I'm implementing the checks now. Thanks again, Matthew

Comment: @MatthewDaly : you are welcome, please accept the answer if you find it helpful.